# How to build binary in package in Golang?

Tags: windows, build, go

I have a project in github.com/user called project:

```
src/
    github.com/user/project
        sub1/
            main.go
            sub1.exe (??)
        sub2/
            main.go
            sub2.exe (??)
```

I am trying to compile the package in my project. When I:

```
$ cd github.com/user/project/sub1
$ go build
```

Nothing happens. go build seems to finish without complaining, but there is no executable file. How can I build packages into executable?

"go version go1.3 windows/amd64"

Comment: If main.go has a main() function, it should build the executable and call it sub1.exe in Windows. Isn't sub1.exe what you are looking for? Remove it and run `go build` again to see if it is created.

Comment: Hm, there is no executable. I am in the directory of the package. I am using Windows, but building from cygwin commandline. But even when using Windows cmd, there is no executable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you name your file `main.go` or `shubudoo.go`. The only thing what matters if you want to build an executable (a command) is that your files start with `package main`. One more thing: Go has **absolutely** **no** notion of "subpackage": All packages are equal for the compiler. The filesystem nesting is for your convenience only.

Comment: So, it's not possible to have a main() in a package other than main?

Comment: The link is what I meant. It's a new main package in a project.

Comment: I have to admit I do not understand your question. Any package which is declared `package main` must have a `main()` function and the go tool will build such a package into an executable and the main() function will be called when you run the executable. Regarding camget: camget is such a `package main` package and it contains a main() function an it is built into an executable. It does not matter if other packages, other non-main-packages, completely unrelated stuff to Go or whatever lives in other directories (higher up, siblings or subfolders).

Comment: My misunderstanding was, that I thought I could build packages into executable binaries, if the packages provided a `main()`, regardless of whether the package is `main` or `cmd` or `xxx`. I thought the `main()` decided whether there is an executable.

Comment: No, it is `package main` *and* `func main() {` for an executable.